# Azure web job keep restarting

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs, kudu

I've created a console application that I run as a continuous web job. It does not use the web job SDK, but it checks for the file specified in the WEBJOBS_SHUTDOWN_FILE environment variable.

I have turned the 'Always On' option on, and I'm running the job in the shared plan as a singleton using the settings.job file.

The web job keeps getting stopped by the WEBJOBS_SHUTDOWN_FILE and is restarted again after that.

I've been looking in the kudu sources, but I can't find why my web job is restarted.

Does anybody have an idea why this happens?

This is the code that initializes the FileSystemWatcher:

```
private void SetupExitWatcher()
{
    var file = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("WEBJOBS_SHUTDOWN_FILE");
    var dir = Path.GetDirectoryName(file);
    var fileSystemWatcher = new FileSystemWatcher(dir);

    FileSystemEventHandler changed = (o, e) =>
    {
        if (e.FullPath.Equals(Path.GetFileName(file), StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0)
        {
            this.Exit();
        }
    };

    fileSystemWatcher.Created += changed;
    fileSystemWatcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.CreationTime | NotifyFilters.FileName | NotifyFilters.LastWrite;
    fileSystemWatcher.IncludeSubdirectories = false;
    fileSystemWatcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
}
```

Comment: Can you please share some code?

Comment: If you are on a "Shared" plan then you cannot set "Always On" which is probably the reason why your WebJob is stopping. Other reason could be that the WebJob binaries are changing from some reason which causes the WebJob to restart. Anyway you can look at/provide the WebJob log file to get some more information on the reason.

Comment: You're right, I changed to Standard and then switched to 'Always On'. The problem still occurs. It looks like a memory problem in the worker, the worker process gets really big (> 1G).

I think this is the reason the process gets killed, but I cannot find anything in the log files.

I'm rewriting the worker to not consume as much memory, if that works I'll answer my own question. :)